# How to count row in particular form post id from the wp-db7 forms

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

mysql_select_db("drreddy", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_db7_forms", $link);

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

var_dump($num_rows);

echo "$num_rows Citizens\n";

?>
```

Comment: what do u get right now?

Comment: please clear what exactly you want

Comment: <?php

      $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
      mysql_select_db("drreddy", $link);
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT form_post_id, COUNT(*) as COUNT FROM wp_db7_forms WHERE form_post_id='63' GROUP BY form_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC", $link);
      $row = mysql_num_rows($result);
     /* echo $row ."Organization";*/
      ?><?php echo $row + 172; ?>

Comment: Thanks I got Answer

Answer (score 0):

```
  $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

  mysql_select_db("drreddy", $link);

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT form_post_id, COUNT(*) as COUNT FROM wp_db7_forms WHERE form_post_id='63' GROUP BY form_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC", $link);

  $row = mysql_num_rows($result);

  echo $row ."Organization";
  ?>
```

or 
 Persons